# Get value of textlength of left characters before decimal point(.)

Tags: vb.net

How can I get the textlength of left characters before decimal point(.)?

Sample Run1:
Textbox7.text = 9.48 03/21/2014
Expected Result = 09.48 03/21/2014

Sample Run2:
Textbox7.text = 9.8 03/21/2014
Expected Result = 09.08 03/21/2014

```
    'If Val(TextBox7.Text.Trim.Split(".")(1).Length = 1) Then
        '    TextBox7.Text = "0" + TextBox7.Text
        'End If
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know why this showed up in my question list with an accepted answer, but what you have looks much more complex than needed. This seems to work on your test data:

```
Dim temp() As String = TextBox7.Text.Trim().Split(". ".ToCharArray())
TextBox7.Text = String.Format("{0:D2}.{1:D2} {2:MM/dd/yyyy}", _
          Integer.Parse(temp(0)), Integer.Parse(temp(1)), Date.Parse(temp(2)))
```

Once I realized that the 9.8 and 9.48 were times (the .8 threw me for a while), I also came very close to getting a version that worked using `Date.ParseExact(TextBox7.Text, "h.m M/d/yyyy").ToString("hh.mm MM/dd/yyyy")`. However, by the time I get the format provider and format string right, my first suggestion will end up just as easy.

Comment: Can I have one last question?, in my case I have 2 Textbox. Textbox3.Text = 02.02 03/26/2014 And TextBox9.Text = 21.01 03/25/2014. How can I compare the last characters month, day, and year or the completedate. Textbox 3 is greater than textbox9 because Textbox3 day = 26 and Textbox9 = 25.

Comment: This is my code: If Val(Strings.Left(TextBox3.Text.Trim, 5)) > Val(Strings.Left(TextBox9.Text.Trim, 5)) Then 'FrmMessageboxNG.ShowDialog() End If